# Find the most common value in a table [SQL,MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I couldn't find much information that would help me find the most common value in a table so here I am. The table (ticketFlightNumber) as you can see is below, and I have to return the most popular flight from this table.

For instance in this picture, flight UA245 would be returned as it is the most used flight in the database.

[image: Table from ticketFlightNumber]

Can someone please help me identify a query which would be robust enough to return a flight/a list of flights which are the most popular?

Thanks!

Please note: columns 1-19 are different *connecting flights* and their values are varchar

Comment: This could potentially solve my problem except I have to check all columns 1-19 and it's a string not an integer... will try the method however and update

Comment: First fix your schema design. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet

Comment: @Strawberry The reason the table is designed like this is because there's no way I could conceive where I could have the database somehow convey information regarding multiple flights or "legs" of the journey. I resolved to using this design because realistically no one will ever have more than 19 connecting flights. I'd welcome another schema design but I couldn't think of one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The query which @Gordon works with slight changes,

```
select flight, count(*) as c
from ((select `1` as flight from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `2` from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `3` from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `4` from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `5` from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `6` from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `7` from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `8` from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `9` from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `10`  from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `11`  from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `12`  from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `13`  from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `14`  from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `15`  from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `16`  from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `17`  from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `18`  from ticketFlightNumbers) union all
(select `19`  from ticketFlightNumbers)) t
group by flight
order by c desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another schema design:

```
ticket_no*,leg*,flight_code

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```

The other answers should seem ridiculous by comparison.

```
ticket_no leg flight_code
        0   1 UA123
        0   2 UA245
        1   1 UA123
        1   2 UA245
        1   3 UA245
        1   4 UA123
        2   1 UA666
```

Comment: Alas, I didn't think of this earlier but this definitely makes sense however you would have similar complexity in terms of runtime when you begin to search for all the legs of one ticket. The problem for me is I have to find the most active flight... In other words, the flight that is used the most by all the tickets. In this scenario, your table would have a similar complexity compared to solutions below wouldn't it?

Comment: No. This is the correct approach. If you provide a desired result, we'll show you how to achieve it using the above schema.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In this case, for me to find the the most frequently used flight number, I could do the following:
`select count(*) where flight_code = "UA123" ` and do this for all the other flight numbers...
This is definitely a viable solution, I'll change my schema because this is a better way to go about it. Thanks :)

Comment: Not quite. To find the most frequently used flight code (a tie in this instance), you could use this (other solutions are available): `SELECT x.flight_code
  FROM 
     ( SELECT flight_code 
            , COUNT(*) total
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY flight_code
     ) x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM my_table GROUP BY flight_code ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1 ) y
    ON y.total = x.total;`

Comment: Ohhhhh. Sorry I'm new to  SQL haha. That's good.

Answer (score -1):

You need to unpivot the data and aggregation.  In MySQL the simplest method is `union all`:

```
select flight, count(*)
from ((select `1` as flight from t) union all
      (select `2` from t) union all
      . . .
     ) t
group by flight
order by count(*) desc;
```

You can add a `limit` to get the most common value.

Comment: Does `select "1" as ...` shouldn't be the column name? if so then doesn't it enclosed with back tick(`)?

Comment: Hey Gordon,
Thanks for taking the time to attempt to solve my issue. I am having issues implementing your potential solution. I was hoping to clarify it.
The table name is ticketFlightNumbers, and this is what I tried to at least test the initial table... this is what I'm getting:
Input:

`select "1" as flight from ticketFlightNumbers union all
select "2" as flight from ticketFlightNumbers`

Output:
`1
1
1
2
2
2`

Comment: @James . . . Yes, they should be backticks.  Double quotes are the standard, but MySQL doesn't support that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, it considers as a value instead of a column.

Answer (score -1):

first off thanks to @James and @ Gordon for helping. Arguably, James' solution is better here's mine if anyone is interested.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.1= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.2= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.3= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.4= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.5= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.6= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.7= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+ 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.8= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+ 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.9= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.10= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.11= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.12= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.13= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.14= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.15= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+ 
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.16= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+ 
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.17= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.18= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+ 
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.19= "UA123" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM ticketFlightNumbers t
```

Since this project is being done in JSP, the Flight number in quotes is replaced dynamically by java through a while loop which loops over all known flight Numbers and runs this query each time.

Again @James and @Gordon, their solution is better since all the work is done with one query.